# Если у родителя не выставлены размеры, то ребенок не отобразится?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Предположим есть некий `main-container`, которому задано -

```
.main-container
    width: 100vw
    height: 100vh
```

В него вложен другой, просто `container`, в который вложен `div` с шириной и высотой 100%.
Это нормально, что последний `div` не отображается? И если да, это нормально, то есть способ "не думать о размерах родителя"? Пишу на `sass`.

Просто получается сейчас, что я пишу код и уверен что "что-то" отобразится, так как задал родителям размеры. Но не могу быть уверен, что завтра не забуду кому-то выставить и потом придется думать..

Как в `css` вообще правильно поступать с размерами и процентами?

Comment: @Alex: в соседнем вопросе выложил код, и вот если я sliding-panel размеры коментирую, то чилда не видно. Но у чилда размеры в процентах.

Comment: @Alex: его нет, он shadow dom...